# Chef: cannot load such file -- rubocop/formatter/checkstyle_formatter

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, rubocop

I'm running the following command:

```
rubocop --require rubocop/formatter/checkstyle_formatter --format RuboCop::Formatter::CheckstyleFormatter --no-color --silent --rails --out checkstyle.xml
```

And get this error:

```
C:/opscode/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubocop/formatter/checkstyle_formatter (LoadError)
```

Environment is Chef-DK 0.4.0 on Windows. I've installed the gem with:

```
gem install rubocop-checkstyle_formatter
```

RuboCop (0.28.0) is delivered within Chef-DK 0.4.0 and without Formater it is working.

Here is the page of the Formater: https://github.com/eitoball/rubocop-checkstyle_formatter

I didn't find any solution by searching with google or here in stackoverflow.
Any tipps how to fix or analyse the problem? I'm new to Ruby.

Comment: It is really strange. I've tried several things:
- Set, change and deleted GEM_PATH, GEM_HOME etc.
Nothing helps. Ruby didn't find the Formatter.
Then I've deinstalled Chef-DK and cleaned all environment variables.
After a fresh install it works fine. It finds the previously installed gems.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue in a relatively hacky way but it works. So basically cd into your rubocop gem folder (like /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/rubocop-0.34.2/lib/rubocop), then you'll see a dir named formatter, then cd into that formatter folder, you'll see a bunch of .rb files for different formatters.
Now here comes the solution.

```
touch checkstyle_formatter.rb
```

then copy https://github.com/eitoball/rubocop-checkstyle_formatter/blob/master/lib/rubocop/formatter/checkstyle_formatter.rb to the file you just created.

Then you should be good to go